# Looking for algorithm to help determine shortest path from one terminal screen to another

Tags: python, graph-algorithm

I am using a terminal client to interact with a mainframe computer.  The entire interface is based on the concept of screens.  An example workflow might look like:

- Login Screen: enter login credentials, press enter
- Menu Screen: enter the number of the menu item you want (lets say "6" for memos), press enter
- Memo Screen: enter account number, press enter
- Add Memo Screen: enter memo details, etc, press enter to save, F3 to go back

I have written a python application to automate the processing of records through this terminal interface.  One of the difficulties I am having is that there are a lot of different screens and my application right now is pretty dumb about how to get from one screen to another.  It can go from the login screen, to adding memos.  But, if it finds itself on the memo screen and needs to de-activate an account, it has to logout and login again because it only knows how to get to the deactivation screen from the login screen, not from the add memos screen.

So, I would like to create a "map" in my application that links each screen to the screens that are "next" to it.  Then, I need an algorithm that could tell how to get from any screen A to any screen B in the shortest manner possible.

I already have some screen objects setup and have "related" them to the screens next to them.  So, I am looking for some kind of algorithm that I can implement or python library that I can use that will do the work of calculating the route from one screen to another.

Edit: I realize that I am looking for some kind of shortest-path graph algorithm.  What is currently throwing me is that I don't really have a "distance", I just have nodes.  So, I really don't want shortest-distance, I want least-nodes.

Comment: did you ever study networking algorithms? If not, I think reading about that can be helpful

Comment: For each screen, I'd store the path from the menu screen to the particular screen and back.  (Of course you could choose any other "main" screen instead of the menu screen.)  To enter a screen, use the path from the menu screen, and after done with this screen, just go back.  This wouldn't always use the shortest path, but it's simple. :)

Comment: @llazzaro: yes, but its been a long time ago and I'm hoping someone can just suggest an algorithm.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: there are a couple problems with that A) there is more than one menu screen (there are several) and B) I am trying to do this as efficiently as possible.  The terminal interface is already slow and I am sometimes processing thousands of records.  So, knowing the direct path from one screen to another, without always using a central reference point is preferred.

Comment: Set distance to 1 between every connected node. Then least distance == fewest nodes.

Comment: @Wilduck: that is a good option and what I will probably go with it.  I was just thinking there might be an algorithm out there that doesn't take into account distance.

Comment: Ok, I guess that I didn't understand how this menu is structured.. It isn't a standard "tree" menu, is it? Because if it is, the obvious solution would be to store where you are, and then go back until the first common parent between where you are and you want to go..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am using an unweighted graph, it looks like the simplest approach is going to be Breadth-first search:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

**Edit:** I found a library which does everything I need:

http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a topology of the screens, the A* algorithm should work fine.